# Phonegap add splash screen in config.xml flle not working?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, splash-screen

i have used this code in my config.xml file (myapp_folder/config.xml) not in www directory. (myapp_folder/res/screen/android/mysplash-screen-image)

```
  <platform name="android">
    <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
</platform>

    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
```

not showing splash screen images. now i have checked the (platforms/android/res/drawable-port-hdpi) that folder is blank .

can you help me. How to Show my Custom Splashscreen on android?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using phonegap build forum then **density** attribute is deprecated. Please use **qualifier** attribute instead of density.

Ex:

```
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
```

For more info refer http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
```

where **screen** is your image name. 
In your case, you have given different image names. Put your images under res->drawable folders, no need in www.

Comment: write @Imran but i think how to add splash screen images in config.xml file? i think don't need res->drawable folders.. can you help me?  res/screenandroid/my-splash-screen-images.. how to add config.xml file?